# Increment notification counter from parse.com

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, parse-platform

I have an Image View and putting a text-view on right corner which looks like a notification bubble. I am fetching data from parse to get push notification set on a table (Message) in my database. I want the text to get incremented dynamically on getting a notification. Is there a way to achieve it. Please help!!

```
  <ImageView      
        android:id="@+id/news_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/event_icon" />

 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_alignRight="@+id/news_icon"
  android:background="@drawable/count_bubble"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:padding="4dp" >

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="25"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:textSize="06pt"
      android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Create an Activity which is for handling Parse Push notifications.

Then initialize a static variable  and set to 0 at first time .Then if a push arrives ,increment this variable (i++) and using a interface class ,send this to any activity for UI updates.

I hope this helps..